# docker上でPgAdmin4をデータ入りのDBコンテナに接続する方法がわからない

Tags: docker, postgresql, docker-compose, wsl

Win10でWSL2でデータ入りのDBコンテナにPgAdmin4を接続し、ブラウザから操作したいと考えております。

データ入りコンテナは以下を使用し、こちらはうまく行っているようでクエリを投げるとテーブルが返ってきます。

[サンプルデータ投入済みのPostgreSQL環境をDockerを使って作成する](https://tadaken3.hatenablog.jp/entry/create-postgresql-sampledata)

[docker-composeでPostgreSQLとpgAdmin4を起動するには](https://denor.jp/docker-compose%E3%81%A7postgresql%E3%81%A8pgadmin4%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)

を参考にしていますが、うまくいきません。

具体的には、yamlファイルのあるディレクトリへ移動し、

```
user@DESKTOP:~/docker/postgresql$ docker-compose up -d
Starting postgresql_db_1  ... done
Starting postgresql_adm_1 ... done
```

となり、このあとどうすればよいかわかりません。
教えていただけないでしょうか。

以下、参考までにdocker-compose.yamlファイルの中身になります。

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
  adm:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    volumes:
      - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
# - ./pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin/storage 
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
       PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@localhost
       PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: adminpass
```

**追記**

WSLでdocker-composeして、localhost:80をブラウザから開くと、待機中で反応がありませんでしたが、
Powershellから全く同じことをすると、PgAdmin4をlocalhost:80から開くことができました。
ただ、PgAdminのサーバー設定のホスト名/アドレスをどれにすればよいかわかりません。。
(127.0.0.1:80で試してみましたが、つながらないようでした。)
何を指定すればよいでしょうか？詳しい方、教えていただけますと幸いです。

**再追記**

yamlファイルのimage: postgresをimage: tadaken3/postgres-dvdrental-databaseに変更したところ、

「ユーザ「postgres」のサーバ「postgres」に接続するためのパスワードを入力してください」
となってしまいます。
yamlファイル内のパスワードpostgresを入れてもだめです。
ここは何を指定すれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `docker-compose` を実行した後、ブラウザから `localhost:80` を開くとどうなりますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ブラウザから開くと待機中になってそのままになってしまいます。

Comment: 実際の質問は "PgAdminの使い方が分からない" といった内容に見えます。質問のタイトルや内容を今一度見直してみてください。

Comment: 確かに実際の質問は "docker上でのPgAdminの使い方が分からない"でしたので、修正いたしました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

YAML ファイルに設定した内容をよく確認しましょう。それぞれ以下のように記載されているように見えます。

**PgAdmin のアカウント情報:**

```
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@localhost
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: adminpass
```

**PostgreSQLのアカウント情報:**

```
POSTGRES_USER: postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
POSTGRES_DB: postgres
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。pgadminにログインするときは上のアカウント情報、その後Postgreに接続する際は下の情報を使うということでしょうか？下のパスワードを入れてみましたが、うまく行っていません。。